# grep only the login date and time for the user root from lslogins and display it using echo

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh, echo

this is a quick and a simple question. I'm new to Linux/Unix and very new in writing sh commands.

I'm trying to write a shell script to execute and provide me the output as

> 'The root user's login date and time is'

If I use this command

```bash
lslogins | grep root | grep -v grep
```

Output:

> 0 root                249        0        0 Feb16/03:19 root

But, I'm looking to print only the root user's logged in date and time using the echo oy any other command. I know this is not a code writing forum, but any quick help will be definitely appreciated and I promise to mark the answer.

If I use this command

```bash
lslogins | grep root | grep -v grep
```

it gives me more details other than just the root user's logged in date and time. I would like to print only the date and time of login for the root user.

I'm going to integrate this script to another tool, so when it runs this script it should give me the root user's logged in date and time as an output.

Comment: `lslogins -l root | awk 'NR==2 { print $4 }'`

Comment: FWIW, I rebooted this machine yesterday and am currently `su`d to root. `lslogins` says I last logged in as root in 2022.

Comment: "*lslogins - display information about known users in the system*".  It is not restricted to which users are currently connected to the system.

Comment: @Nic3500 if your comment was to me, my point was that lslogins may have a different idea of what it means to be "logged in" than is actually wanted

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you are new to linux. So here are some pointers,

1. Have a look at `man lslogins` you can do this with any command
2. Have a look at `lslogins --help` you can do this also with most commands

There we see that a possible option is a `-l login` which allows us to select the user. As you are interested in `root`, you could do:

```
$ lslogins -l root
```

Now we are only interested in the `LAST-LOGIN` which is `-o LAST-LOGIN` and `--noheadings`. Finally, we want to change the time-format to something useful:

```
$ lslogins  -o LAST-LOGIN --noheadings --time-format iso -l root
```